# Python: multiple inheritance, super(), HTMLParser and Logger

Tags: python-3.x, multiple-inheritance

I would like to have an `HTMLParser` that would write logs with `Logger` from the `logging` module. I would also like to take advantage of the `super()` syntax.

For that I am using the `adapter` approach from [this well-known blogpost](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/). However, in order to use `HTMLParser`, one needs to overload some methods (like `handle_starttag` and others). I do not understand how (better, where?) I should do that. Here is my [minimal not-working approach](https://gist.github.com/all3fox/e5f99f628b65f7e557c7).

The `handle_starttag` method never gets called, neither in `HTMLParseAndLog` nor in `HTMLParserAdapter`.

Comment: Why do you want to use multiple inheritance at all here? Is this thing you're building supposed to actually *be* a logger, or should it just make calls to one? It seems odd to want something that is both a parser and a logger; they're not roles I'd want to merge.

Comment: @user2357112 you are right, it should just make calls to one. But I would not like to be calling the `ROOT` logger for that matter, I would like a separate logger for each instance of a parser. Which made me think that multiple inheritance is the way...

Comment: Just give it a `self.logger` instance attribute or something.